# Discrepancy in values between Google Analytics and API

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-python-client

I am using Google Analytics API in Python to track 'Downloads' from some websites (on the websites there are available files that people can download and I am tracking how many people did it). 'Downloads' in GA are marked as 'Events'. The data is being checked by me on monthly bases. In 2 out of 35 websites the values of 'Downloads' in my script differ comparing with GA - my script usually shows me lower number than what I see in GA, just in 1 out of 20 months script value was higher. The list of the files that were downloaded is correct (the same in data from API and GA). For all the websites I am using the same code in a loop. I have checked the "sampling" and it is not a problem here.
Any guesses what may cause the issue?
Thank you in advance.

I am attaching part of the code:

```
def get_events_report(analytics, start_date, end_date):
    # Use the Analytics Service Object to query the Analytics Reporting API V4.
    page_ids = get_page_ids()
    report = {}
    start_date = str(start_date)[:10]
    end_date = str(end_date)[:10]

    for country, page_id in page_ids.items():
        print('page_id: ' + str(page_id))
        print('country: ' + str(country))
        n_report = get_batch_report(start_date, end_date, page_id, 0)
        n_report[page_id] = n_report.pop('reports')
        try:
            if n_report[page_id][0]['nextPageToken']:
                print(n_report[page_id][0]['nextPageToken'])
                r = get_batch_report(start_date, end_date, page_id, n_report[page_id][0]['nextPageToken'])
                n_report.update(r)
        except KeyError:
            pass

        report.update(n_report)
        time.sleep(2)

    table = get_events_table(report)

    return table


def get_batch_report(start_date, end_date, page_id, pageToken):
    report = analytics.reports().batchGet(
            body={
                'reportRequests': [
                {
                    'viewId': page_id,
                    'dateRanges': [{'startDate': start_date, 'endDate': end_date}],
                    'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:uniqueEvents'}],
                    'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:dateHourMinute'},{'name':'ga:eventAction'}, {'name':'ga:eventLabel'}],
                    'pageSize': '10000',
                    "samplingLevel": "LARGE",
                    "dimensionFilterClauses": [{
                   "filters": [{
                        "dimension_name": "ga:eventAction",
                        "operator": "PARTIAL",
                        "expressions": ["downloads"]
                    }]}],
                    "orderBys": [
                        {
                          "fieldName": "ga:dateHourMinute",
                          "sortOrder": "ASCENDING"
                        }]
                      }]

                }).execute()
    return report
```

Comment: Show your report GA and call API, pls

Comment: Just did, sorry

Comment: please edit your question and show us what you mean by not correct.  What two figures are you comparing.